# [JavaScript][Angular]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCityData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question has been asked many times before and I've tried the answers but they do not seem to solve the problem I'm facing. I'm new to Angular and am trying to pass a value from the controller to a factory so that I can retrieve some JSON information through an API. While I'm able to get the value from my HTML to the controller, the next step is giving me a TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCityData' of undefined. My controller code is as follows:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope, HttpGetter) { 

var successFunction = function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }

    var errorFunction = function(data) {
        console.log("Something went wrong: " + data);
    }

    $scope.cityName = '';
    $scope.getCityName = function(city) {
        $scope.cityName = city;
        HttpGetter.getCityData($scope.cityName, successFunction, errorFunction);
    };
}]);
```

The factory code is as follows:

```
app.factory('HttpGetter', ['$http', function($http){

return {
        getCityData: function(query, successFunction, errorFunction){
            return $http.get('http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=MyAppKey&q=' + query).
            success(successFunction).
            error(errorFunction);
        }
    };
  }]);
```

I've replaced my App key with the string "MyAppKey" just to be safe but my code contains the appropriate key. Also, it would be very helpful if I could get a bit of an insight on how the function invocations happen because there seem to be a lot of function callbacks happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `undefined` could be because of the service not getting properly injected.

Try:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'HttpGetter', function($scope, HttpGetter)
```

Also as you said, to be on safer side you aren't using the right key, but anyone using your application can get the key by checking the network calls. So, ideally, one should make a call to the backend, and backend will send a call along with the secured key to the desired API endpoint and return the response data to front-end.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem! BTW in angular lingo, are the elements within the square brackets called injections?

Comment: Yea, you got it right. One can explicitly define then too, which is the only way to prevent minification breakdowns. Like: `MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'AnyService'];`

Answer (score 0):

Can be due to `['$scope', function($scope, HttpGetter)` ?

Should be `['$scope', 'HttpGetter', function($scope, HttpGetter)` instead.

Comment: @SyedSafir If this solved your problem, then you should have mark this answer as accepted as it was the first one and the other two were just copies of this.

Answer (score 0):

You used minified  version and inject only `$scope` not `HttpGetter` but used as argument  in controller function that's why got `HttpGetter` is **undefiend** and error shown *Cannot read property 'getCityData' of undefined*

So you should inject `HttpGetter` in your minified version `['$scope', 'HttpGetter'`

use like:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'HttpGetter', function($scope, HttpGetter)
```

instead of

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope, HttpGetter)
```

And if your `MyAppKey` is secured and want to hide from user then you should use it in server side